# Initialize a class function as null

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

My knowledge of typescript is a little rusty. I have a class MyClass that has a member variable that is a function. I do not know what this function will be at compile time. I want external code to be able to set this function as something in runtime, so that it can be called later. What is the syntax in typescript for initializing the function as null/void/undefined and then later checking to see if it is defined so that it can be called?

My code:

```
import { User } from 'User':
export type UserCallback = (user: User | null) => void;

export class MyClass {
    private userInfoChangedCallback : UserCallback (WHAT GOES HERE TO INITIALIZE TO NULL?);

    setCallback(callback: UserCallback) {
        this.userInfoChangedCallback = callback;
    }

    register = async(username: string, displayName: string, password: string) => {
        // do some things here...

        if (this.userInfoChangedCallback == null) {   IS THIS CORRECT FOR CHECKING == NULL?
            this.userInfoChangedCallback(new User(username,displayName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why can't `userInfoChangedCallback` be initialized by `MyClass`'s constructor?

Comment: Anyway, do `private userInfoChangedCallback : UserCallback | null = null;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign that your class member cann be a type or null and then you can assign null as default:

```
private userInfoChangedCallback: UserCallback | null = null
```